# Laravel override delete() on whereIn is not Working

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm making an app that could (soft) delete a post. It will delete the record on database and delete image file on storage, I tried to create an override method for `delete()` in my model and it looks like this

```
public function delete()
{
    $tempImage = $this->image;

    parent::delete();

    $this->imageDelete($tempImage);
}

public function imageDelete($image)
{
    $this->image = null;
    $this->save();

    if (! empty($image)) {
        unlink(public_path() . self::$pathImage . $image);
        unlink(public_path() . self::$pathThumb . $image);
    }
}
```

It works for deleting one record. But, when I try to delete multiple record (using `whereIn`), the override method is not accessed, and the `whereIn` is accessing the real `delete()` method.

This is my controller for delete posts

```
public function delete(Request $r)
{
    Message::findOrFail($r->id)->delete();

    return redirect()->back();
}

public function multipleDelete(Request $r)
{
    Message::whereIn('id', $r->select)->delete();

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

If I delete the records with `multipleDelete()`, It only delete the record on database.

Comment: why not use Message::destroy([1, 2, 3]). Wherein you can pass single or multiple ids on there. You are having longer logic just to delete single and multiple message.

Comment: I need to delete the image of each ids

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What `delete()` that you override is actually Eloquent model delete. However, when you tried to delete directly after `whereIn()`, it is DB query. So it won't go through your model at all. It is using raw sql to delete the data.

What you can do is retrieve the result as Eloquent model first, then loop to delete.

```
Message::whereIn('id', $r->select)->get()->each(function($msg) {
    $msg->delete();
});
```